# ¿Cómo abrir un proyecto de un archivo .rar?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto de laravel en un archivo .rar y quiero saber si despues de descomprimirlo hay forma de que lo pueda abrir o importar en laravel. Estoy usando ubuntu en una maquina virtual

Comment: Que versión de Laravel usas y que sobre que versión tiene el Ubuntu creado en tu maquina virtual ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para abrir un proyecto de Laravel en Ubuntu, según la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#server-requirements) oficial te recomienda como primera opción instalar la maquina virtual de [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead) pero si no lo tienes instalado puedes hacerlo teniendo instalado una versión de PHP mayor o igual a 7.2.5 con todas sus extensiones.

En este caso te voy a explicar como hacerlo con simplemente PHP.

Vas a tener que abrir una terminal en la ubicación que deseas instalar PHP y escribir la siguiente sentencia:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

Esto realizara la instalación de PHP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendrás que esperar que finalice su respectiva instalación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de finalizada la instalación se tendrá que verificar cuales fueron las extensiones que se instalaron junto con la versión de PHP y cuales están pendientes de acuerdo a lo que requiere Laravel, para esto se escribe el siguiente comando:

```
php -m
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de hacerte falta alguna extensión puedes usar el siguiente comando remplazando al final por el nombre de la extensión que te haga falta, por ejemplo en mi caso me hace falta **BCMath** y lo instalo así:

```
sudo apt-get install php bcmath
```

Después de instalada la extensión, verificar nuevamente las extensiones instaladas con `php -m` y comenzaremos con la instalación de Laravel vía [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) para administrar sus dependencias, pero es necesario tener Composer en la maquina virtual.

En la misma terminal donde se instalaron las extensiones previamente vas a escribir el siguiente comando y esperar que finalice su instalación:

```
sudo apt-get install composer
```

Ya después de haber instalado composer y las extensiones que se requieren se va a validar la instalación, vas a abrir nuevamente una nueva terminal pero desde la ubicación de raíz del proyecto descomprimido que traías en tu `.rar` y vas a escribir el siguiente comando para iniciar el servidor de artisan:

```
php artisan serve
```

Y por ultimo la dirección que te muestra en la terminal ejecutarla en tu navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto ya tu proyecto debe estar corriendo de forma satisfactoria. Es un gusto haberte ayudado.